# EMACS pasting html tags twice when copying source code

Tags: html, emacs

when i copy source code from a website into emacs, it's pasting the html tags in twice. i have web-mode.el installed, so i'm assuming it has something to do with my auto-completion, but i'm not sure how to fix this.

what i copy:

```
  ga('create', 'UA-43298913-1', 'site');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>script>
</body> 
</html>
```

what gets pasted:

```
  ga('create', 'UA-43298913-1', 'site');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>script>script>
</body>body>
</html>html>
```

Comment: Do you use emacs in text-mode ? On what OS are you ? Have you downloaded the last version of web-mode ? You can also post an issue on the github repository.

Comment: Can't repro it locally, but it looks like this has something to do with auto-closing tags. You might check what your customization values are for `sgml-mode`. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: i'm using emacs in web-mode, but augmented with web-mode.el (http://web-mode.org/). i do have the latest version.  i've tried switching to text-mode and pasting but it ruins the structure of the html. i'm using cygwin on a pc.

Comment: i really like web-mode, so any advice on fixing this for the future would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am the creator of web-mode. Can you open an issue on github please.

Comment: FYI the issue here https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/issues/103.

Answer (score 0):

I have a "similar" extension in vim.

It does a tag completion attempt whenever you enter `</` into the text in an html file.

My guess is that your "cut/paste" is being "typed" out by emacs and so it types the '

My idea is to try changing how cut and paste is completed in EMACS.

Of course if you haven't changed it to begin with then that sucks.

My second idea would be to look at the settings for the html tag completer extension you have and see if there is something that will keep it from triggering on cut and paste.